# PHP MYSQL Select OneToMany as a nested json

Tags: php, json, mariadb

I've two tables, one being the Customer table and the other the Address table having a one to many between them. I want to select all customers with their respective addresses and displaying it something like this:

```
{
  id: 222,
  name: John Doe,
  age: 32,
  addresses: [
    { id: 1, address: "some address", customer_id: 222 },
    { id: 2, address: "secondary address", customer_id: 222}
  ]
}
```

My code is the following now:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers JOIN addresses ON customers.id = addresses.customer_id";
$result = $connection->query($sql);


$rows = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}

print json_encode($rows);
```

But it results in two records with same data but different address property. How could I achieve the upper example?

Sample data:

customers table:

```
id  | name | age
222 | John | 32
```

addresses table:

```
id | customer_id | address
1  | 222         | Some address
2  | 222         | Secondary address
```

Current result:

```
[
  {
    id: 222,
    name: John,
    age: 32,
    address: Some address
    customer_id: 222
  },
  {
    id: 222,
    name: John,
    age: 32,
    address: Secondary address
    customer_id: 222
  }
]
```

SQL scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


CREATE TABLE `addresses` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



ALTER TABLE `customers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `customers`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

ALTER TABLE `addresses`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`);

ALTER TABLE `addresses`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

ALTER TABLE `addresses`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `addresses_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;


INSERT INTO `customers` (`id`, `name`, `age`) VALUES
(1, 'John', 32);

INSERT INTO `addresses` (`id`, `address`, `customer_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Some address', 1),
(2, 'Secondary address', 1);
```

Comment: which version of mysql you are using ? please share the sample data also.

Comment: Using 10.4.19-MariaDB, will edit the post with sample data in a sec.

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, not as a table.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in the query alone (unless newer MariaDB has some specific feature for it that I don't know about). You can fix this when you iterate through the results though. Add the user id as the key in your `$rows` array. If the key doesn't exist already, add it to the array with a sub array for the addresses and if already exists, then just push the address data to the existing one. However, I don't see any difference between `id` and `customer_id` in your result so you need to fix that in  your query. Maybe PDO has some fetch mode for it.

Comment: there is no pure way in sql only.you can manual loop it assemble the json as you wish in php.or you can use thirdpart ORM like `Eloquent`

Comment: MariaDB 10.4.x does not support JSON_ARRAYAGG() which is needed for described task solving. Version 10.5.0 needed. So you must either upgrade the version or use string functions for to build needed JSON object. See solution for MySQL 8: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=54519d04fb7861870b4c8f80471d3ccc PS. MariaDB does not support JSON datatype, so the array obtained is treated as LONGTEXT which results in excess dquote chars in output (additional clearing needed).

Comment: Alright, I will just transform my data with PHP, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to solve the issue on DB side you can use `JSON_ARRAYAGG` function in you query:

```
    SELECT 
        `customers`.`id`,
        `customers`.`name`,
        `customers`.`age`,
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(`addresses`.`address`) AS `addresses`
    FROM `customers` 
    JOIN `addresses` ON `customers`.`id` = `addresses`.`customer_id`
```

[Here You can test this query and PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=9d21ca36dcf7dd42e57443501ebe250a&sqlses=dfc99fb9d7603a0fd36afeccb821aaaf&php_version=php8&sql_version=mariadb)

The PHP solution can be next:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT 
            `customers`.`id`,
            `customers`.`name`,
            `customers`.`age`,
            `addresses`.`address`
        FROM `customers` 
        JOIN `addresses` ON `customers`.`id` = `addresses`.`customer_id`
    ";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);


$rows = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (is_array($rows[$row['id']])) {
        array_push($rows[$row['id']]['address'],$row['address']);
    } else {
        $rows[$row['id']] = $row;
        $rows[$row['id']]['address'] = (array)$rows[$row['id']]['address'];
    }
}

var_export($rows);
```

[Run MySQL and PHP code online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=5f00ea168f946bd47ab49ec38aafa90d&sqlses=dfc99fb9d7603a0fd36afeccb821aaaf&php_version=php8&sql_version=mariadb)